# Can't get permission for partitioned disk

Tags: permissions, cp, chmod, readonly

When I tried copying files from my Home/Downloads folder to other partition of my hard drive, it returns the message 'Permission Denied'.

I tried few of these:
[image]

It just says: 'Read-only' whatever I try.

I'm on Manjaro GNOME

Comment: Welcome to the site. If at all possible, please avoid attaching screenshots of text. They are often difficult to read, and contributors will have to type-copy commands you used in order to understand what the problem may be.

Comment: Thank you, I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was because of Windows. Even if 'Turn on fast startup' is unchecked, this problem might occur.

What fixed the problem is, I booted into windows, then I shut it down, and again boot into Linux.

Previously, I restarted from Windows to Linux, I think that might have caused the problem because I guess Windows automatically goes into fast startup mode while restarting.

By the way, thanks @Karov

Answer (score 1):

your filesystem is mounted as read only. you need to remount it as read-write.

```
mount -oremount,rw /filesystem
```

Comment: filesystem can be found using `df -h .`

Comment: I ran ' mount -oremount, rw 'New Volume' ' New Volume is the parition. After that, I got new error. https://imgur.com/a/1WMTfzW